# Enable TLS certificate verification for AWS RDS MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, amazon-rds

I use MySQL 5.7.17 on AWS RDS.

I encountered a strange behavior and I am looking for an explanation.
In short: I try to connect over SSL, with settings that I think should cause the connection to *FAIL*, but it succeeds!

The following PHP code succeeds to connect to the RDS instance over SSL:

```
<?
$HOST = "something.amazonaws.com";
$USER = "myuser";
$PASS = "mypass";

$connectionString = "mysql:host={$HOST};charset=utf8";
$options = [ ];
$options[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA] = "LITERALLY THIS TEXT. DEFINITELY NOT A CERTIFICATE!";
$options[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT] = false;

$conn = new \PDO($connectionString, $USER, $PASS, $options);
$sql = "SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([ ]);
$stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($rows);
```

The result I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Variable_name] => Ssl_cipher
            [Value] => AES256-SHA
        )

)
```

Also, I found three `pem` files in `/etc/ca-certificates/rds-mysql`. I thought that PHP might be going there for some reason, so I deleted them, but the SSL connection still succeeds.

Note: if I delete the line that says `$options[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA] = "LITERALLY THIS TEXT. DEFINITELY NOT A CERTIFICATE!";` - it does NOT connect over SSL. So it appears that this option does have some impact.

My question is: how come it succeeds?

Comment: You're passing in junk but you're also saying "don't bother to verify". Have you tried with verification enabled?

Comment: @tadman it doesn't work with MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT turned on, but this is the client-side validation, right? Isn't there supposed to be some validation done by the server as well?

Comment: Have you checked that the server is set to verify?

Comment: I haven't checked. I wasn't aware that it was configurable. Do you know which option controls it?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_require_secure_transport

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-encrypted-connections.html#mandatory-encrypted-connections

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks. These links seem to be about forcing SSL connection. The question is about validating certificates when an SSL connection is attempted...

Comment: Unless the server requires SSL, it will allow a client to connect without SSL.

Comment: @BillKarwin this is not the issue. The issue is that the client connects WITH SSL and I'm trying to understand if MySQL can *reject* the connection if the client doesn't have the appropriate certificates...